# (C++) How do you Display a 2D Array with both Char and Int Values?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, integer

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

string display[2][3] = {{"Name","Geometry","English"},{"Larry",90,85}}; //problem is here
    
    for(int row=0;row<2;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
            cout<<display[row][col]<<" "; 
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

//[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: You cannot have such an array. Do you want string values `"90","85"`?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to create a table with those values.

Comment: In other words: array must be homogeneous. You cannot put `int` in a `string` array. You can put a string that says `"90"` for example, but is that what you want? You will not be able to, e.g. add two numbers like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have array of only one type. In your case array of strings. So if you want to put your integers into this array you can use:

```
std::to_string(some_int);
```

so it will be:

```
string display[2][3] = {{"Name","Geometry","English"},{"Larry",std::to_string(90),std::to_string(85)}}; //problem is here
```

Answer (score 0):

I take a guess here, but I have a feeling you took a wrong tool for the job.

It seems that you want structure like CSV file, with first row as header and remaining rows as data. This cannot be done using arrays, because arrays must be homogeneous. You cannot store multiple types in there.
You can of course convert `int` to a `std::string`, see the other answer for that, but if the next step will be e.g. finding mean of the scores, it suddenly becomes much more difficult.

The better solution to store multiple types of data would be to create a class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int geometryScore;
    int englishScore;
};

int main()
{
    Student students[1] {{"Larry",90,85}};
    std::cout << "Name Geometry English\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << students[i].name << " " << students[i].geometryScore << " " 
                  << students[i].englishScore << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see...Thank You For Your Help!